# MongoDB GridFS one-to-one query effeciency in Ruby

Tags: ruby, mongodb, gridfs

I'm using MongoDB w/ Sinatra for an iPhone app.

I have a `users` MongoDB collection and a `picture` GridFS collection. Each user has one picture, so, initially, I just set the `ObjectId` for the picture to be the same as the corresponding user. That made it easy to, [given the user's ObjectId, get the picture of that user with just one query](https://github.com/acani/acani-sinatra/blob/46c2bddf97d21f7c9797d79d5265945202a1dddc/acani.rb#L102). Then, I was planning to store the MD5 hash of the picture in the user object so that the iPhone would know to download the picture only if the MD5 hash had changed. This would work, but I had to [modify the `Grid` Ruby class to get the MD5](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+in+Ruby#comment-66996092)

But then, [Kyle Banker](http://kylebanker.com/blog/) [suggested](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+in+Ruby#comment-67362080) that I just store the `picture_id`, instead of the MD5, in the user object. But, if I do that, given a user `ObjectId`, I'd have to first query the `picture_id` from the user, and then query the picture (2 queries). Is there a way, in one query, to get the picture given a user's `ObjectId`? Reading up on [GridFS indexes](http://www.mongodb.org/display/DOCS/GridFS+Specification#GridFSSpecification-Indexes), I think there's a way to store the user's `ObjectId` in the meta data of the picture and then set an index on that field. That way, I could do it in one query. If that's correct, what's the code look like to do that in Ruby?

Alas, should I even bother? I could just as easily use the `picture_id` to query the picture, which is what I'll do for now, but it'd also be nice, from a syntactical perspective, to be able to query the picture (in one indexed/fast query) by the `user_id`. Kinda like Facebook's graph api lets you do, e.g., http://graph.facebook.com/mattdipasquale/picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure. Like you suggest, just store the user_id somewhere in the picture's file object, and build an an index on that field.

Comment: Cool. I'm just querying by `picuture_id` for now. But, if I wanted to, should I do something like: `@grid.put(image, :metadata => "4ce533a41467286a14000269")` and `coll.create_index("metadata")`?

Comment: You should be able to do @grid.put(image, :user_id => foo)

Comment: Any options passed that aren't official options will be saved as extra keys. See the API docs: http://api.mongodb.org/ruby/1.1.2/Mongo/Grid.html